# How to connect two Google sheets without using Query and importrange

Tags: python, database, google-sheets, google-apps-script

Hi everyone I need help 
I'm new at my work and I've been given the task to connect two Google sheets they use as databases .

I simply need a way of copying lines from one Google sheet to another automatically and without taking the formula just the values plainly. I'll need a tutorial because I'm new and my knowledge of Google sheets apps is inexistent.

No, they won't learn SQL  No, it can't be done with the functions Query or import range because the constant request is making the Google sheet unworkable. No, I can't use zapier or any other app, it's forbidden. I need to find a way, Maybe using Google app for Google sheets?

Comment: Sounds like Google Apps Script is the way to go.  No one can help you, however, if you don't share a sample of what you are trying to achieve.  There are already a lot of examples of how to copy data to other spreadsheets here on this network.  I would recommend looking into those, make an attempt on your own, and then post a question that is unique to your situation, if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? What initiates the  action to copy data?

Comment: @Cooper I guess a time trigger, like for example everyday check if all lines available in Google sheet A appear on Google Sheet B and if not start to copy them

Comment: Hi @Codedabbler I'll do! Thx for the suggestion I'll keep updating the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy changes from one sheet to another using timebased trigger that you create

```
function triggerhandler() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast("Trigger");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:E10").getValues().flat();
  const bu = sh.getRange("A1:E10").getValues();
  const last = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('last');
  if(!last) {
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put('last',JSON.stringify(vs))
  } else {
    let comp = JSON.parse(last);
    if(vs.some((e,i) => e != comp[i]) || comp.length != vs.length) {
      CacheService.getScriptCache().put('last',JSON.stringify(vs),1800)
      let osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
      osh.getRange(1,1,bu.length,bu[0].length).setValues(bu);
      ss.toast('Sheet0 has been updated');
    }
  }
}

function whatsincache() {
  Logger.log(CacheService.getScriptCache().get('last'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="33" rows="12">${CacheService.getScriptCache().get('last')}</textarea>`),"Dialog")
}

function removelast() {
  CacheService.getScriptCache().remove('last')
}
```